# SQL join double counting

Tags: mysql, sql

I've found somewhat similar posts, but can't figure out how to apply in my case.  Essentially in joining two tables I'm getting double counting in the output. Here's what I'm looking at:

#### Table 1 (t1)

```
Name    |  Type  |   Count
Chris      Blue      3
Chris      Red       2
Steve      Blue      10
Steve      Red       5
Steve      Green     4
Peter      Blue      7
```

#### Table 2 (t2)

```
Name    |  Hours  
Chris      2.4 
Steve      1.5
Peter      0.2
```

#### Query

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.type, t1.count, t2.hours / count(t1.name) as avg_hrs
FROM t1 JOIN t2 on t1.name = t2.name
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.type
```

#### Desired output

```
Name    |  Type  |   Count  |  Hours
Chris      Blue      3         1.2
Chris      Red       2         1.2
Steve      Blue      10        0.5
Steve      Red       5         0.5
Steve      Green     4         0.5
Peter      Blue      7         0.2
```

#### Current output

```
Name    |  Type  |   Count  |  Hours
Chris      Blue      3         2.4
Chris      Red       2         2.4
Steve      Blue      10        1.5
Steve      Red       5         1.5
Steve      Green     4         1.5
Peter      Blue      7         0.2
```

The 'Hours' column is coming out wrong. Basically, I want to divide the hours in t2 by the number of occurrences of the name in t1; instead I am getting the full value of t2.hours for each row in the newly produced table, which is leading to a bunch of double/triple counting when I look at the aggregate table.

Any ideas on how to fix?  Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as:

```
select t1.name,
       t1.type,
       t1.count,
       t2.hours/t1count.total as hours
  from t1 
       inner join t2 on (t1.name = t2.name)
       inner join
         (select name, count(*) total
            from t1
           group by name) t1count
        on (t1.name = t1count.name)
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27a07a/4